# Switch Columns From Two Different Tables in SQLite

Tags: sqlite

I have a SQLite database with two tables. Each table has the same number of rows, a little over 5M. However, when writing the database, my code misallocated one row on each table so my database looks like this:

```
Col name [contains] (datatype)
TA                  TB

KE [Pk] (int)      KE [Pk] (int)
A1 [A1] (int)      B1 [B1] (int)
A2 [B2] (int)      B2 [A2] (int)
A3 [A3] (int)      B3 [B3] (int)
...
A9 [A9] (int)      B9 [B9] (int)
```

To Fix it, I wrote the SQL Script Below:

```
--Create New Table To Store A2
Create Table "A2Act" (
"Pk" integer,
"A2True" integer);

-- Copy A2 to A2Act
Insert INTO A2Act
Select KE, B2
FROM TB

-- Copy B2 to TB
Update B2
Set B2 = (Select A2 From TA Where TB.KE = TA.KE);

-- Copy A2Act to TA
Update A2
Set A2 = (Select A2True From A2Act Where A2Act.KE = TA.KE);

-- Drop A2Act
Drop Table A2Act;
```

However, this code, although it seems to work, is taking multiple hours per file to run. Is there any way to make this change faster?

Answer (score 0):

Your logic is correct.

If your version of SQLite is 3.33.0+ you can use the join-like [`UPDATE ... FROM ...`](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_update.html#update_from) syntax to improve performance:

```
CREATE TABLE TBcopy AS
SELECT KE, B2 FROM TB;

UPDATE TB
SET B2 = TA.A2
FROM TA
WHERE TB.KE = TA.KE;

UPDATE TA
SET A2 = TBcopy.B2
FROM TBcopy 
WHERE TA.KE = TBcopy.KE;

DROP TABLE TBcopy;
```